# Creating New Column in Salesforce Report

Tags: reporting

I want to create a new column in my custom report.

Scenario: I have a object say Ticket and it has two field created_date and closed_date. Now I want to create a column called Age(number) of that ticket. which is calculated by closed_date - created_date.

I achieved this by creating a new formula field in Ticket Object.

But can I do this without creating a custom field in object. Is there any way to create a temporary field just for report? In report builder there was one option to add formula field but to create a formula with my date fields is not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In reports, it is not possible to create a formula in reports which calculate date/date time difference.

Currently having a field on object seems to be the only alternative.

You can try upvoting this idea- [Add formula field to Tabular Reports](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kpBVAAY), Once it reaches 2.5k points salesforce might consider it.

---

Edit: Good news, this idea has been delivered as reported by [Greg C](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/97878/greg-c)

Comment: The idea has been delivered https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdWu1UAF/custom-calculations-on-reports-at-the-row-level-not-summary

Answer (score 1):

This feature is sadly(and unbelievably too) not available in Salesforce. Following is a idea post for this feature, you may want to vote it. This will omit the need of adding custom formula fields for the sake of reports. As of now, custom fields are the way out.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kpBVAAY